# How can I make a fixed menu with scrolling in IE

Tags: html, css, menu, scrollbar, window-resize

Please help me to fix menu on the top of the body and that should be scrolled horizontally.

I used `position:fixed` for the particular `<div>` tag with `top:0;left:0` values. But when I resize the window to 50%, the fixed menu appearing only 50% remaining part was got inside the border (not appearing).

Please make me to fix this problem to view the menu with scrolling when we decrease the window size..

Comment: Can you post some code? It'll make any examples given more valid for you, as well as help those answering

Comment: <div class="fix">  is fixed div and the below code is CSS

.fix {
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 z-index:9999;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) this will help you to fix the nav bar and this will not disturb the page on resizing the content. You can see the example [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Comment: It never happens I think you may be doing something wrong open the above example and the check that. Paste your code in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and add the link in the question